# Why is 'it' a personal pronoun?

Tags: single-word-requests

It might be a silly question but personal pronouns should refer to people, isn't it?

Comment: If both your rear wheels get flats because they drove over nails, would this bother you?

Comment: @tchrist if we say It is cold, the subject is the day, not a person..

Comment: No, when we say "it is cold", the subject is "it". There is no day there. It would appear you are making up very weird things, and then asking other people why the very weird things you made up are very weird. Well, I dunno. Why indeed.

Comment: @RegDwigнt no, you are wrong, Im just trying to undestand something very clear, see the answer below. And don't loose your time saying to me if I'm weird, that's weird...

Comment: When you talk about your new tires and say how shiny **they** are, it doesn't matter to you that your tires aren't your buds?

Comment: *It* does refer to persons, at least sometimes.

Comment: @RegDwigнt This seems a very valid question for [ell.se]

Comment: meta: Frankly, (and let me make it clear, no offense), I've seen questions that do not merit posting even on [ell.se] getting up votes and getting answers and answers getting up votes, all in a matter of 24 hours.  Let's at least not mock at genuine questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is addressed by [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_pronoun):

> Personal pronouns are pronouns that are associated primarily with a particular grammatical person – first person (as I), second person (as you), or third person (as he, she, it, they). [...] The term "personal" is used here purely to signify the grammatical sense; personal pronouns are not limited to people and can also refer to animals and objects (as the English personal pronoun *it* usually does).

In other words, it’s because “grammatical person” does not have to refer to people.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but would add that it is helpful to understand there are other types of pronouns which convey different meanings than the personal pronouns (i.e. demonstrative, possessive, reflexive, relative, interrogative, etc.).  These other types of pronouns have person and gender too, but they perform some other grammatical function beyond merely substituting for a noun in the nominative or oblique cases, which is all the personal pronouns really do.

Comment: In other words, "person" in grammar is not the person as in "person, place or thing" (also grammar). Beats all logic.

Answer (score -2):

Because modern English doesn’t have a gender-neutral singular personal pronoun, and while historically this was dealt with by the gender-neutral usage of “he” in these contexts, this is no longer accepted usage, and as a result, in order to refer to a singular person in a gender neutral fashion, you need to use either “it” or “they”, or constructions like “he or she”.

Comment: What. Since when is "he" not accepted usage. Since when is "it" accepted instead. And how is singular "they" a new thing, it's been around for many, many hundreds of years.

Comment: This isn't correct.  Personal pronouns are merely a class of pronouns that substitute for a noun in the nominative or oblique case.  They don't serve the same grammatical function as other classes of pronouns (e.g. possessive, reflexive, demonstrative, etc.).

Comment: @Talmage: I meant personal pronoun in the sense of “pronouns that refer to a person,” e.g. he, she, I, they, etc. If you’ve got a better word to use for them, I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: @RegDwight: Using a gender-neutral “he” hasn’t been accepted since feminism became a thing, decades ago, at least not in any moderately formal setting (e.g. academic writing). I’m fairly certain there’s a number of academic style guides that explicitly state as much, but I’m posting this from my phone so I can’t look them up at the moment.